# startAgent.bat startAgent closes itself when the running process runs

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I want to see the resource usage using jmeter perfmon metrick colector listener, for this listener I support the listener with PerfMon Server Agent.

but after I run the startAgent.bat file and do running in jmeter suddenly the startAgent.bat window closes itself

Answer (score 0):

In order to see where the problem is you need to run `startAgent.bat` in a separate instance of [Cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) or [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/), this way the terminal will keep running when/if the Java process finishes and you will be able to see the output.

Otherwise you can check the log file.

Most probably you're suffering from [SIGAR bug #136](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar/issues/136), the PerfMon agent process dies because `sigar-amd64-winnt.dll` is not compatible with Windows 10+. You will need to rebuild it using Windows 10+ SDK and replace problematic .dll with the new one.

There is a fixed version build by a community member [here](https://github.com/cnstar9988/sigar/raw/master/sigar-amd64-winnt.dll) you can use it on your own risk.

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics)

Alternatively you can [enable Windows SSH server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui) and go for [SSHMon Plugin](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon)